# How should i put color in specific result in DataGridview. if Working Status is Green if Not Working Color Red

Tags: vb.net

How should I put a color in specific result if Status is Working and if Not Working is Red? I tried some code but I'm still getting the same color either it's Not Working.

My code:

```
        LblMessage.Text += "Working"
        dt_row_result = dt_result.NewRow()

        dt_row_result("URL") = PROTECTED_URL
        dt_row_result("Status") = LblMessage.Text.ToString()
        dt_row_result("Checked Time") = DateTime.Now()
        dt_row_result("Comments") = "No Issue"
        dt_result.Rows.Add(dt_row_result.ItemArray)
        DataGrid.DataSource = dt_result
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt_result.Rows.Count() - 1
            DataGrid.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green

        Next
    End If

    Continue For
Catch ee As Exception
    If dt_row_result Is Nothing Then
        dt_row_result = dt_result.NewRow()

    End If
    dt_row_result = dt_result.NewRow()
    LblMessage.Text = "Not Working"
    dt_row_result("URL") = PROTECTED_URL
    dt_row_result("Status") = LblMessage.Text.ToString()
    dt_row_result("Checked Time") = DateTime.Now()
    dt_row_result("Comments") = "Issue"
    dt_result.Rows.Add(dt_row_result.ItemArray)
    DataGrid.DataSource = dt_result

    For i As Integer = 0 To dt_result.Rows.Count() - 1
        DataGrid.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red

    Next
```

Comment: It is hard to tell what that code is doing since the block states and stops are missing.  But you dont need to loop thru the DGV rows.  use the RowPrePaint or CellFormatting event instead

Comment: @Plutonix Good day. may i know if what RowPrePaint do? the system is checking the url if Working or Not Working. i tried some codes but if the Status is Not Working the Green color is on their, Once Not Working it will be Red in Column in DataGrid. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting

Dim drv As DataRowView
If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
    If e.RowIndex <= ds.Tables("TableName").Rows.Count - 1 Then
        drv = ds.Tables("TableName").DefaultView.Item(e.RowIndex)
        Dim c As Color

        If drv.Item("FieldName").ToString = "N" Then
            c = Color.Green
        Else
            c = Color.Red
        End If
        Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("FieldName").Style.BackColor = c
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Assume that `N` and `Y` is the `Status`.
So if `Fieldname` = `N` Then the color is Red,
and if the `Fieldname` = `Y` then the color is Green.

Hope this help.

**Updated** :

```
  Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGrid.CellFormatting
    For i As Integer = 0 To dt_result.Rows.Count() - 1

        If dt_result.Rows.Count() - 0 Then
            DataGrid.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green
        End If

    Next
    Dim drv As DataRowView
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        If e.RowIndex <= dt_result.Rows.Count - 1 Then
            drv = dt_result.DefaultView.Item(e.RowIndex)
            Dim c As Color
            If drv.Item("Status").ToString = "Working" Then
                c = Color.Green
            Else
                c = Color.Red
            End If
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = c
        End If
    End If
    DataGrid.DataSource = dt_result
    Dim drv As DataRowView
    Dim drvs = dt_result

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method that runs on row data bound for the gridview. Then do a check on the status and set the cell colours to what you want.

Comment: Hello Good day Thanks on response. ill check and do on my side Thank you